# Subversion HTTP LimitExcept options

Tags: svn, https, webdav

This question is simple: I am trying to configure my personal SVN repository to allow certain actions without password. To do this I must configure the LimitExcept options on the https configuration, but I haven't been able to find any document that specifies exactly what each one of the labels PROPFIND, OPTIONS, REPORT, GET, etc. Exactly allow.

Could somebody point me to the right document?

Answer (score 0):

I've never come across documentation for this either.  One approach would be to map them by watching the apache logs while performing operations.  I think you will find that it's very difficult (if not impossible) to map HTTP methods (get/put/delete) to logical version control operations (update/commit/merge).

You simply need more information than just the http method names and their order of appearance.